# Permissions for AWS Step Function tutorial

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am new to AWS step functions and was trying to follow this tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-human-approval.html#human-approval-yaml but I am getting permission errors on Step#2 when importing YML template in cloud formation service.

```
"The following resource types are not supported for resource import: AWS::ApiGateway::Account,AWS::Lambda::Permission,AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine"
```

Our AWS admin granted me the following permissions:

```
IAM Full Access
SNS Full Access
STS_AssumeRole  *
Lambda_FullAccess
AWS StepFunction_FullAccess
APIGatewayAdministrator (Equals Full Access)
```

He also said that the following services are used:

```
ApiGateway::RestApi
ApiGateway::Resource
ApiGateway::Method
ApiGateway::Account
ApiGateway::Stage
ApiGateway::Deployment
IAM::Role
Partition
Lambda::Function
Lambda::Permission
StepFunctions::StateMachine
APIGatewayEndpoint
SNS::Topic
```

But I am still unable to import the YML template from tutorial.
What's missing? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrbuG.png)
Thank you

Comment: Did you accidently do an import from existing resources rather than create new stack?

Comment: No, I had created a new stack as per tutorial

Comment: Hmm "The following resource types are not supported for resource import" is associated with import. Are you creating via console?

Comment: yes, from console

Comment: Can you double check it again definitely making sure you are selecting import existing resources on the CloudFormation screen?

Comment: When creating a stack I see two options:with new resources(standard) and with existig resources(import resources). I tried both. The first one gave blank red error message on the top and " Failed to upload template. JSON or YAML formatted file" message under the file box. The second option failed with :The following resource types are not supported for resource import"  red message

Comment: The first option is the correct one, try uploading again. No idea why blank red box but that might be a error on AWS side

Comment: Works now, I've used option 2.Still had to sign of and sign back but it worked on the second try. Thank you so much

Comment: Have added the answer in case anyone else gets the error

Answer (score 0):

After relogging in and attempting again the solution appeared to work.

The error indicates that it was initially tried using "Import Resources", whereas it was new resources being created.

Comment: Thank you mokugo-devops

Comment: Thats no problem, glad I could be of helps @mikesv :)